# Why does UICollectionView's cellForItem at index path get called for ALL cells right at the start

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Why does UICollectionView's cellForItem at index path, get called for ALL cells before it displays. Shouldn't the collectionView just get the cells that it needs..i.e. the cells that will be displayed on the screen like a tableview would?

Steps

- Storyboard with ViewController. ViewController has CollectionView. CollectionView has vertical flow layout.
- ViewController has IBOutlet for the collectionView and implements the collectionView's data source and delegate methods
- Within the data source and delegate methods cells (that use autolayout for their size) are passed to the collectionview .. cell for item at index path

Placing a print statement before the cell is passed, shows that all of the cells are requested before the collectionview is shown on the screen.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var flowLayout=collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout;
        flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width:20,height:30);
        self.collectionView.register(UINib(nibName:"ShortCell", bundle:nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ShortCell");
        self.collectionView.register(UINib(nibName:"LongCell", bundle:nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "LongCell");
    }
}

extension ViewController:UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 500;
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let row=indexPath.row;
        print("row:",indexPath.row);
        let rem = row % 2;
        if(rem==0){
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ShortCell", for: indexPath);
            return cell;
        }
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "LongCell", for: indexPath);
        return cell;
    }
}
```

Why does the collectionview need to get all the cells before it displays? Why doesn't it only request cells in a piecemeal manner like a tableview would? Is this an issue?

Comment: hmmm? I just ran your code in  a new test view controller, and only the visible and partially visible cells are requested.

Comment: Are your cells using autolayout for their size?

Comment: I just created basic cells in external xib files, and ran your code without edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of investigating...

When using `flowLayout.estimatedItemSize`, auto-layout makes a layout pass to calculate how many cells will fit ***at that estimated size***, ignoring any auto-sizing within the actual cells.

So, if you change `.estimatedItemSize` to an actual *estimated size*, you should only get (about) the number of calls to `cellForItemAt` as needed.

Just be careful that you don't *over-estimate* the size. If you do, you either end up with a whole bunch of

> The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
>   the item width must be less than the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and right values, minus the content insets left and right values.

error messages, or you get goofy (inaccurate) sized scroll indicators.

Comment: Made my estimated size close to the real size of the cells and the uicollectionview started working as expected, only getting cells when needed! Thanks for the tip :)